# Convertir sub arrays multidimensionales en arrays planos

Tags: javascript

Tengo este array resultante de una función:

```js
final = [ 
          [ 
            [ 0, 'Bowling Ball' ],
            [ 0, 'Dirty Sock' ],
            [ 0, 'Hair Pin' ],
            [ 0, 'Microphone' ] 
          ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ] 
        ]
```

Mi objetivo final es este:

```js
final = [
          [ 0, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 0, 'Dirty Sock' ],
          [ 0, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 0, 'Microphone' ] ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ]
        ]
```

Es decir, quiero eliminar los *arrays* anidados repetidos. Esto más o menos creo que lo puedo hacer pero sólo si antes se alguna manera convertir el *array* multidimensional a uno plano. Es decir, así:

```js
final = [
          [ 0, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 0, 'Dirty Sock' ],
          [ 0, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 0, 'Microphone' ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ]
        ]
```

Como veís, se ha elminado un *"nivel"* y ahora todos los *"sub.arrays"* están en el mismo nivel (alrededor del *array* exterior).

Sólo encuentro métodos para lograr "planificar" el *array* completamente (es decir, que sólo queda un *array* al final y todo esta junto), pero no para esto último.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```js
function flattenDeep(final) {
      return final.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
    }
    flattenDeep(final);
    
    // final devuelve esto:
    
  final =  [0, "Bowling Ball", 0, "Dirty Sock", 0, "Hair Pin", 0, "Microphone", 1, "Hair Pin", 1, "Hair Pin", 1, "Hair Pin", 1, "Half-Eaten Apple", 1, "Half-Eaten Apple", 1, "Half-Eaten Apple", 1, "Half-Eaten Apple", 1, "Bowling Ball", 1, "Bowling Ball", 1, "Bowling Ball", 1, "Toothpaste", 1, "Toothpaste", 1, "Toothpaste", 1, "Toothpaste"]
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que has intentado? Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código así podemos ayudarte a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Hecho. Lo que he intentado me devuelve un sólo array con todos los datos juntos. Se me había ocurrido hacer un array por cada 2 items pero eso me parecía aún más complicado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema con tu función `flattenDeep` es que no se detiene en el nivel que estas necesitando, es decir, convierte todos los `Array` y solo necesitas que convierta los `Array[Array]`.

### Solución:

Para lograr las dos cosas, aplanar y filtrar los duplicados, podrías hacerlo así

```js
let array = [
  [
    [0, 'Bowling Ball'],
    [0, 'Dirty Sock'],
    [0, 'Hair Pin'],
    [0, 'Microphone']
  ],
  [1, 'Hair Pin'],
  [1, 'Hair Pin'],
  [1, 'Hair Pin'],
  [1, 'Half-Eaten Apple'],
  [1, 'Half-Eaten Apple'],
  [1, 'Half-Eaten Apple'],
  [1, 'Half-Eaten Apple'],
  [1, 'Bowling Ball'],
  [1, 'Bowling Ball'],
  [1, 'Bowling Ball'],
  [1, 'Toothpaste'],
  [1, 'Toothpaste'],
  [1, 'Toothpaste'],
  [1, 'Toothpaste']
];

function aplanar(arr) {
  let res = []
  arr.forEach(val => {
    res = res.concat(Array.isArray(val[0]) ? aplanar(val) : [val]);
  });
  return res;
}

function filtrarDuplicados(arr) {
  let hash = {};
  return arr.filter(val => {
    let key = JSON.stringify(val),
      existe = hash[key] !== true;

    hash[key] = true;
    return existe;
  });
}

// Aplanamos
let aplanado = aplanar(array);
console.log('aplanar(arr): ', JSON.stringify(aplanado));

// Filtramos duplicados
let filtrado = filtrarDuplicados(aplanado);
console.log('filtrarDuplicados(arr): ', JSON.stringify(filtrado));
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar una función especial para *aplanar* tu arreglo hasta 1 nivel de sub-arreglos.

Para lograrlo, estoy incluyendo en mi `script` una función que te devuelve el máximo de sub-niveles de un arreglo, de Kyle Phillips, que he encontrado en [este repositorio de github](https://gist.github.com/hapticdata/08c9d7f9e18e2ab72e715264c251f46e)

```js
/* https://gist.github.com/hapticdata/08c9d7f9e18e2ab72e715264c251f46e
*/

const maxDepth = (a)=>{
  let maxVal = Number.MIN_VALUE
  let item

  a.forEach(val=>{
    let depth = max(val)
    if(depth > maxVal){
      maxVal = depth
      item = val
    }
  })

  return item
}

/**
 * find the maximum depth of nested arrays
 * @param {Array} a
 * @param {Number}[count]
 */
const max = (a, count=0)=>
    Array.isArray(a) ? max(maxDepth(a), count + 1) : count

inicial = [ 
          [ 
            [ 0, 'Bowling Ball' ],
            [ 0, 'Dirty Sock' ],
            [ 0, 'Hair Pin' ],
            [ 0, 'Microphone' ] 
          ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Hair Pin' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Half-Eaten Apple' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Bowling Ball' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ],
          [ 1, 'Toothpaste' ] 
        ];
       
let final = [];       

//función especial para _aplanar_ hasta 1 nivel de sub-arreglos
function aplanar(value, index, array) {
  let valuedpth = max(value, 0);
  if (valuedpth <= 1) {
    final.push(value);
  } else {
    value.forEach(aplanar);
  }
}

let inicialmaxdpth = max(inicial, 0);

if (inicialmaxdpth > 2) {
  inicial.forEach(aplanar);
} else {
  final = inicial;
}

console.log(final);
```